# Maven dependency using older version of transitive dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to use a dependency `org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.23.0` and it `mvn dependency:tree` in an empty(demo) maven application is:

```
[INFO] \- org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.23.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.23.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO]    \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.3.0:compile
```

However, in my main application's child module its tree looks like:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
```

I don't understand why it's using older version of `spring-beans` and other ie `4.2.5` where even in my main application it should have used version `5.1.2`. Help?

Note:
The child module which I'm having problems in have a parent module which uses spring-beans 4.2.5 but I'm unable to understand why spring-beans:5.1.2 is not getting used which is a direct dependency of `org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.23.0` [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-spring/2.23.0).

Comment: Please show your full pom file...

Comment: Hello. IMO, you have another dependency or dependencies that require `spring-beans 4.2.5`.

Comment: try to run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=rg.springframework:spring-beans:jar` it will show you only dependncies that require/use spring-beans dependency, As @Mickael mentioned you have another dependency with old version

Comment: @Mickael, that was it. I dint search to explicit dependency which was 4.2.5. thanks mate.